# ¿Como paso una estructura a una funcion, C++?

Tags: c++, funciones, estructuras-de-datos

Me piden hacer un programa que lea, **nombre**,**código**, y **3 notas**,  todo es de 10 estudiantes;  en un vector estructurado llamado **vec_est** ,  mi problema es al momento de de enviar la estructura a la función.

```
include stdio.h
include stdlib.h
include string.h
include conio.h


struct vec_est
{
    char nombre[10];
    int codigo;
    float notas[3];

}vecest[2];

int fun_promedio(struct vec_est);

main()
{
    const int est =2;
    const int no = 3;
    int i=0,j=0;
    float promedios[3];

    for(i=0;i<est;i++)
    {
        printf("ingrese el nombre[%d]\n",i);
        scanf("[^\n]",&vecest[i].nombre);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("ingrese el codigo de estudiante [%d]",i);
        scanf("%d",& vecest[i].codigo);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("ingrese 3 notas\n");
        for(j=0;j<no;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&vecest[i].notas[j]);
            fflush(stdin);
        }
    }
     fun_promedio( vec_est); // aqui es que me da el error al conectar la funcion// . 
}

int fun_promedio(struct vec_est)
{
    int j=0,i=0;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            printf("el valor es de %d\n",vecest[i].notas[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Una esrtuctura se puede pasar como parametro a una funcion como cualquier otro tipo de dato. Al pasarse como parametro se efectua una copia, por lo cual es recomendable pasarlo como referencia ya que las estructuras son generalmente mas pesadas que los datos simples

Comment: en si , como la función main() llama esos valores ?... cuando escribo el nombre de la función   ejemplo  **int func_promedio(structura,tamaño)** me dice marca error en la llamada ..... me dice el compilador error de dato(struct,int)    y disculpa la ignorancia

Comment: Sería bueno que añadas el código que llevas escrito.

Comment: ya lo subi ... las screen estan aki  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GyLEzkWElP4G-g5SUN1wDypE6s3lbs1z ,, y esta  https://drive.google.com/open?id=107s_49i6pVSa9lENIO44JzkeurnULN2v

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es que la función reciba un array debes declarar el parámetro como tal:

```
int fun_promedio(struct vec_est []);
//                              ^^
```

Comment: oh.... muchas gracias .. tenia esa duda ,  :) gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder